# Does a user role change remove their Profile2 fields?

Tags: 7, users

Say I have a user role PendingArtist, and its [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) fields: skills and about me.

How do I change the role of a user? And does the role change delete the PendingArtist's Profile2 fields?

Edited: Don't know why I asked this, could have tried it out myself. Please ignore this question.

Comment: are using profile2 only or in combination with profile2_regpath?

Comment: The new role does not have a profile2 access? OR... Why would changing a role cause profile2 fields to disappear?

Comment: @NoSssweat Profile2 fields are associated with users, not with roles right?

Comment: `their role gets changed to ApprovedArtist, and they retain their Profile2 fields that were associated with the old role?` you make it sound here as if their profile2 were not retained when you change role.

Comment: yes my bad I need to reword that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Profile2 in combination with [Profile2 Reg Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) (which you probably do or in this case - might as well use it), then you'll find two sections when you are editing Profile2 (*at admin/structure/profiles/manage/profile_name_here*) :

1. **Roles** - that's where you assign which roles will have the fields from Profile2;
2. **Assign Roles During Registration** - that's where you set the roles to assign to a newly registered user if user creates a profile following the path you've set.

So, in your application you'd check "PendingArtist" and "ApprovedArtist" in *`"Roles"`* section, so that your fields show up for both of those roles. Then, in *`"Assign Roles During Registration"`* section you would check only "PendingArtist", so that only PendingArtist role gets assigned to a newly created user. In the end, when the role of PendingArtist is changed to ApprovedArtist - the data entered in profile2 fields remains as entered originally.